# How To Determine When a web browser control Is Done Loading in windows phone

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I am writing application in windows phone 8 and i have web browser control.

Web Browser control fires the Load Completed event when it is finished loading a HTML.But i have HTML with java script.And java script load after some time of Load Completed method.I want to put loder in this java script load.

My C# code is

```
 string htmlString = "<!-- BEGIN FUSION TAG CODE - DO NOT EDIT! --><style type=\"text/css\">img{ width:60%;}</style> <div><div id=\"proactivechatcontainer51ujohwy0o\"></div><table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"2\" cellpadding=\"2\" width=\"90%\" style=\"FLOAT: left ;MARGIN-LEFT: 150px; MARGIN-TOP : 150px;\"><tr><td align=\"center\" id=\"swifttagcontainer51ujohwy0o\"><div style=\"display: inline;\" id=\"swifttagdatacontainer51ujohwy0o\"></div></td></table></div> <script type=\"text/javascript\">var swiftscriptelem51ujohwy0o=document.createElement(\"script\");swiftscriptelem51ujohwy0o.type=\"text/javascript\";var swiftrandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*1001); var swiftuniqueid = \"51ujohwy0o\"; var swifttagurl51ujohwy0o=\"http://support.coretalkgroup.com/visitor/index.php?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\";setTimeout(\"swiftscriptelem51ujohwy0o.src=swifttagurl51ujohwy0o;document.getElementById('swifttagcontainer51ujohwy0o').appendChild(swiftscriptelem51ujohwy0o);\",1);</script><!-- END FUSION TAG CODE - DO NOT EDIT! -->";



var htmlCode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlString);
            WebView1.IsScriptEnabled = true;
            WebView1.NavigateToString(htmlString);
```

How can i put?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can write an anonymous function that will start as soon as script will be loaded.

```
(function(){
   //js is loaded
}());
```

Comment: @MansinhDodiya
I'm not sure if web browser control supports same function as IE but you can try handle state change event (http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/how-to-detect-when-an-external-library-has-loaded/).

Or load script with ajax request (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: @dwmkalkov: its possible in windows phone 7?